# MongoClient handling extended network outages

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am writing a data logging application which writes to a mongoDB hosted in the cloud.  The location I will be running this application from has a very poor connection to the network and frequently is unable to connect for hours at a time.  It is not an option to solve the obvious network reliability problem.

I would like my application to try to store records into the DB until connection is lost.  At this point I would like to buffer the records internally until they can be written to the db again.  The problem I am having is with all of the re-connection and retry attempts handled internally by the C# mongo driver I am having trouble determining a connection loss and when I do it I don't understand how to stop the driver from reattempting.  Ideally, it would fail on the first attempt and I would buffer.  I then have some code to try and re-establish the connection every 15mins or so since the data making it into the DB is not time sensitive.

What actually ends up happening is I lose connection and without even attempting to send any records the driver senses the network connection loss and starts throwing hundreds of exceptions per minute:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException' in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException' in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.NameResolution.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.NameResolution.dll
```

How I connect:

```
    try
    {
        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
        clientSettings.ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        clientSettings.ServerSelectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        clientSettings.SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        clientSettings.WaitQueueTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        clientSettings.HeartbeatTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        clientSettings.RetryWrites = false;
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        // No network connection
        mongoClient = null;
    }
```

How I check if the connection is there:

```
    private static bool IsClusterConnceted
    {
        get
        {
            if(mongoClient != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _ = mongoClient.ListDatabaseNames();
                    return mongoClient.Cluster.Description.State == ClusterState.Connected;
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    // Command timed out because we lost connection
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `retryWrites` URI option to false to stop the driver from retrying on errors (unless you are using withTransaction helper).

The driver does attempt to reconnect in background when it doesn't have established connections, so you are going to see some warnings pertaining to lack of connectivity.